# The tcblisting enviroment dosen't work when using it to build a macro

Tags: listings, tcolorbox, verbatim

I want to build a macro with the `tcblisting` enviroment from `tcolorbox`, as shown below, but fail. What's the reason and how to deal with this?

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry,tcolorbox}
\geometry{showframe}
\geometry{left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}
\parindent0pt

\begin{document}
This works all right as expected.
\begin{tcblisting}{}
  \rule{1in}{5pt}\\\parbox{1in}{some text}
\end{tcblisting}


Construct a macro with the above code, but the macro does not work, why and what is the solution?
\newcommand\qa[2][]{
  \begin{tcblisting}{#1}
  #2
  \end{tcblisting}
}
\qa{\rule{1in}{5pt}\\\parbox{1in}{some text}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Verbatim environments often can't be hidden inside commands.

Comment: Besides `\qa` not working because you can't have verbatim in the argument to a command, what would be the advantage of `\qa` over the environment form?

Comment: @egreg Sometimes simple verbatim may be used in which an enviroment is too heavy. And verbatim not working as an argument to a command is very annoying in some cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verbatim mode requires disabling or modifying a lot of TeX features and conventions.

For instance, you don't want to interpret the backslash as introducing a command, but also interpret newlines to actually produce a new line; and so on.

What happens when TeX reads the argument to a command? Well, it forms tokens using its standard way of doing things and in your case you'd need to undo this work, which is impossible in full generality. You might “stringify” the input, but this would add spaces after control sequences and newlines would not be preserved, because they've already been converted to spaces or even to `\par`. For instance the input

```
\ttfamily
\detokenize{a\xyz\uvw b

c}
```

would produce

[image]

Not what you'd like, I guess. There are tricks around this, see for instance `\lstinline{<verbatim material>}` but you can't have braces in the verbatim material; `listings` offers `\lstinline<char><verbatim material><char>` where the `<char>` stands for a character not appearing in the verbatim material, but newlines would not be honored (they'd cause an error message actually).

The only safe method for general verbatim material is to use an environment form.